# How can I import scripts from another directory?

Tags: python, import

I have absolutely scoured, but cannot find a solution to my below situation.

- I have a folder: Tasks.
- Inside Tasks are the folders Task1, Task2, Task3 etc.
- Also inside Tasks is a folder called Modules which houses several shared scripts that need to be
  accessed by scripts inside Task1, Task2, Task3 etc.

I'd love to be able to access the scripts inside 'Modules' from inside scripts in 'Task1'. How can I achieve this?

I've given everything it's own `__init__.py` file.

I've tried using absolute paths - it says Module does not exist.

I've tried using `sys.path.insert(0, "Path/To/Modules")`, then importing it - it says Module does not exist.

I've tried using `from .. import Modules` - it says Module does not exist.

At the moment I've just copy & pasted every required script into every separate Tasks folder, but would love to just have them all imported from the Modules folder so changes are easier to make.

---

Example:
Inside Tasks/Modules are a few scripts: "generate_API_Token.py" and "API_Connect.py"
Inside Tasks/Task1 is a script "do_task_1.py"

From inside Tasks/Task1 I would love to be able to import and use the classes inside Tasks/Modules/generate_API_Token.py.

I'd love to structure it this way as the generate_API_Token classes are used for each of the tasks and it makes sense to make changes in only one place.

Inside "do_task_1.py" i've tried (separately):

```
import absolute.path.to.generate_API_Token

import absolute.path.to.Modules

from .. import generate_API_Token

from .. import Modules

from .. import Modules.generate_API_Token
```

I've also tried (separately):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "Path/To/Modules")
import Modules

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "Path/To/Modules")
import generate_API_Token
```

Each time it errors with "No module named 'Modules'".

Attempts starting with 'import .. from' error with 'attempted relative import with no known parent package'

I'm using VS Code with the main 'Tasks' folder open, so from inside Tasks/Task1/do_task_1.py I would have guessed that it would be able to 'import from ..'

I totally understand that what i've tried is not really helpful as I don't understand why I can't just import from a nearby folder. I hope it's clear what i'm trying to achieve though.

Thank you

Comment: Please show a [mre] consisting of the exact directory and file contents, as well as the command you use to run the program and the information what is the working directory from which you run the command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.